# Picking a suitable mechanism for error reporting: How can I change a macro at compile time?

Tags: c, macros, exit

I want my program to report a different exit code from each improper exit, so something like

```
fprintf(stderr, "bad foo in bar (%d)", -1);
exit(-1);
...
fprintf(stderr, "bad baz in qux (%d)", -2);
exit(-2);
...
fprintf(stderr, "bad boop in bing (%d)", -3);
exit(-3);
```

and so on for each place exit may be called. Since maintaining the number of places could be a big pain, I want to use a macro:

```
MY_ERR("...")
```

which expands to

```
do{ fprintf("...""(%d)", --EXITCODE);
    exit(EXITCODE); } while(0);
```

So the question becomes, what is EXITCODE? If it's a normal C variable, then it's only decremented at runtime, and it will exit immediately, so each error will not have a unique number and the number will always be -1 (if EXITCODE starts at 0). But if it's a `#define`d macro, then we can't decrement it.

Is there a way to do what I want? I guess I could use `__LINE__`, but that won't work across multiple files. I could use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in combination, but that can't be a code to `exit`.

Comment: BTW, you probably don't want to have `;` at the end there, so that you can use your macro as `MY_ERR("...");`; after all the point of `do {} while(0)` in macro is to make it behave like one statement.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to create a table containing all your error codes. An enum or a const array. You need some sort of documentation over the meaning of those magic numbers anyhow.

For example:

errors.h

```
typedef enum
{
  ERR_BAD_FOO,
  ERR_BAD_BAZ,
  ERR_BAD_BOOP,
  ERRORS_N
} err_t;

void error_then_exit (err_t error);
```

errors.c

```
#include "errors.h"

void error_then_exit (err_t error)
{
  const char* ERR_STR [] =
  {
    "bad foo in bar",
    "bad baz in qux",
    "bad boop in bing"
  };

  _Static_assert(ERRORS_N == sizeof(ERR_STR)/sizeof(*ERR_STR), 
                 "Errors in the error handler!");

  int code = -(int)error;

  fprintf(stderr, "%s (%d)\n", ERR_STR[error], code);
  exit(code);
}
```

Usage:

```
#include "errors.h"

error_then_exit (ERR_BAD_FOO);
```

Comment: (Avoid naming your types `_t` if you care about POSIX.)

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, there are only 128 exit codes (0–127) you can use as exit codes 128–255 are overloaded by the shell for program termination by signal. In a medium-sized program, this isn't nearly enough to give every `exit` call a different exit code. This is also not what the user wants: After all, the user has never read your source code. The user wants to know *why* the program terminated, not *where* it terminated.

My suggestion is to make up a rough set of conditions why your program fails and assign an error code to each one. You can look at [FreeBSD's set](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&sektion=3) for inspiration. Consider that the exit status is only used for scripts to determine what action to take. It must be coarse enough not to be a pain-in-the-ass to decode but fine enough to be useful.

Put all other information (like in which source file the failure occured) in the error message. Be verbose and write the error message so the user has a chance to understand what action he can take to resolve the problem.

Comment: The shell? What shell? How do you know what OS he is using?

Comment: @Lundin I don't. Does that matter?